# Better filereading and print formating in R

Tags: beginner, strings, formatting, r

I am a beginner using `R` and I am trying to solve some simple statistics problems and print the output. The following code takes in two datasets, computes the mean, variance and standard deviation. Finally it computes a 95-confidence interval for the standard deviation.

This is just a sample and my real data consists of a couple of thousand values, the files below are just for illustration.

Currently I read in my data files as follows

```
list(as.numeric(unlist(read.table(filename)))
```

however, I strongly feel there must be a better method? My datafiles
usually consists of rows of data (anywhere from 3 to 10 columns) and about a 1000 rows.

Secondly I find myself doing the following a lot

```
cat(paste(c("Confidence Intervall for the standard variation: (",
            f(CI.sigma.low[1]),", ",#
            f(CI.sigma.high[1]),")\n"), collapse = ""))
```

I tried to create a function that does this, however, I ran into problems when dealing with
multiple values.

**I am not looking for feedback on the mathematics. Only syntax, and tips on how to 
improve the overall structure of the code**

## Code

**data_01.txt**

```
34.10
34.21
33.34
35.45
31.56
34.67
36.72
33.16
34.35
34.50
```

**data_02.txt**

```
38.82518 37.61011 39.70940 41.19950 37.91823 39.06883 41.86497 38.87179
39.72824 39.46657 36.42833 39.73950 38.15764 38.49400 37.96093 38.31201
41.23278 37.50835 39.25816 39.72357 37.11235 38.84875 37.88969 38.86277
```

**Main.R**

```
EXERCISE <- 1 # Global variable, 

# Shorthand for printing without " or numbers
p <- function(text,value) {
  cat(paste(c(text,value,"\n"), collapse = ""))
} 

# Rounds number to X decimal places
f <- function(num, decimals=3) {
  round(num*10^decimals)/10^decimals
}

# Fancy title for the problems
problem <- function(index=EXERCISE) {
  w <- strrep("=",80); w.small <- strrep(" ",35)

  cat("\n\n"); cat(w,"\n")
  p(c(w.small,"Problem 3",letters[index],w.small),"")
  cat(w,"\n\n")
  #double << increments out of current scope
  EXERCISE <<- EXERCISE + 1
}


problem() # Problem 3a

# A list makes it easy to change or add files
filenames = c("data_01.txt",
              "data_02.txt")
kvm <- list()
for (i in 1:length(filenames)) {
  kvm[i] = list(as.numeric(unlist(read.table(filenames[i]))))
}

# Applies the function "length" to each element of "kvm" u.z.w
N <- sapply(kvm, length, simplify = TRUE)
mu <- sapply(kvm, mean, simplify = TRUE)
sigma <- sapply(kvm, sd, simplify = TRUE)

p("Number of values: ",N[1])
p("  Expected value: ",f(mu[1]))
p("        Variance:  ",f(sigma[1]^2))


problem() # Problem 3b

I <- 0.95 # 95-confidence intervall
alpha <- 1 - I

# qchisq is the Chi-squared Distribution
# df= degrees of freedom (frihetsgrader)
# CI = confidence interval
CI.sigma.low = (N-1) * sigma^2 / qchisq(1-alpha/2, df=N-1)
CI.sigma.high = (N-1) * sigma^2 / qchisq(alpha/2, df=N-1)

cat(paste(c("Confidence Intervall for the standard variation: (",
            f(CI.sigma.low[1]),", ",#
            f(CI.sigma.high[1]),")\n"), collapse = ""))


problem() # Problem 3e (T-interval)

I <- 0.95; alpha <- 1 - I

d.f <- sum(N) - length(N)
sigma.p <- sqrt(sum(sigma^2*(N-1))/d.f)

p("Pooled variance: ",f(sigma.p^2))
p("Pooled standard deviation: ",f(sigma.p))

v.p <- qt(1-alpha/2, d.f) * sigma.p * sqrt(sum(1/N))

CI.diff.mu.low <- (mu[1] - mu[2])-v.p 
CI.diff.mu.high <- (mu[1] - mu[2])+v.p 

p1 <- "Confidence Intervall for difference "
p2 <- "between mean values (mu_1-mu_2):"

cat(paste(c("\n",p1,p2,"\n","  (",
            f(CI.diff.mu.low),", ",#
            f(CI.diff.mu.high),")\n"), collapse = ""))
```

Comment: I have a few questions. Is it intentional that you treat all the values from `data_02.txt` as one variable even though they are in different columns? What problem are you actually trying to solve? Are you practicing `cat()` statements? From outside, I would, for example, rather use named vectors, a custom method (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/6583639/2563804), or create a table. Furthermore, it seems to me that some of the code is reinventing the wheel (e.g., `t.test()` provides the CI for differences between means).

Comment: In summary, there is nothing inherently wrong with the code, but the direction for improvements depends on the desired result and the aim of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing the print formatting part of your question, base R's `sprintf` function handles all the formatting you're looking for and a lot more besides.

`sprintf` takes exactly one format string - which includes both your text and the placeholders for your variable data, including formatting instructions like numbers of decimal places and the variables. Its remaining arguments being the variable data to be  inserted into the string.

So with an example similar to yours:

```
> x <- 1.23012
> y <- 1000.0001

> # Equivalent to your paste solution
> cat(paste("My results are", f(x,2), "and", f(y,0), "\n"))
My results are 1.23 and 1000 

> # Problem - Won't display trailing zeroes, if you want to display to the full number of digits
> cat(paste("My results are", f(x,3), "and", f(y,0), "\n"))
My results are 1.23 and 1000 

> cat(sprintf("My results are %1.3f and %1.0f\n", x, y))
My results are 1.230 and 1000
```

It's a lot more powerful than simply `paste`-ing snippets of strings together; is really good for tabular output - e.g. if you want your data to fill a certain number of characters in the output; and once you get the hang of it, pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be a complete review, but the base R function `round` has an optional second argument `digits`. It works like this

> ```
> > round(1.234567, digits=1)
> [1] 1.2
> > round(1.234567, digits=2)
> [1] 1.23
> ```

Therefore there is no need for your function `f`.